# Posting a Json String to WebApi always end up with null parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have been trying to resolve this issue. I have a WebApi that accepts a Json String as a POST. The client is hitting our Webapi. However, **"Result"** is always NULL. I have been researching for several days but could not find an answer. I am using Postman to post the response to the WebApi. I am new to WebApi and this is my first post. Hope someone can shed some light on this. thank you

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new 
    HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
    config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationFilterAttribute());

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
    );
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

**OcrDataReceiverController.cs** - "Result" is always NULL

```
[RoutePrefix("api/OcrDataReceiver")]
[Authorize]
public class OcrDataReceiverController : ApiController
{   
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]OcrResultModel result)
    {
    // Do Something
    }
}
```

**OcrResultModel.cs**

```
[Serializable]
public class OcrResultModel
{                       
    public string requestId { get; set; }      
    public string customerRequestId { get; set; }
}
```

Since I am new to stackoverflow, I can't post any images (postman) yet. In postman, I have Content-Type = application/json.

Body: Raw - JSON(application/json)

```
{"requestId":"2b20cba5-6715-4d3e-aea6-9e72088d87bc","customerRequestId":"Joseph123d"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Serializable` from class. it will work.

As Json.NET serializer by default set the `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` to true, so it ignores the properties

```
public class OcrResultModel
{                       
    public string requestId { get; set; }      
    public string customerRequestId { get; set; }
}
```